# Button and Link not working

Tags: php, html

In my web application I have an images and each and every image has button for like as well as name of the user who uploaded it.User name is a link. But in my code both link and button not work.Both are not clickable.
Here is my code

```
     <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
  mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
   $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id  WHERE flag=1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC; ")     or die(mysql_error());


//Puts it into an array

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
  //Outputs the image and other data 
  ?>

  <div class="test" id="<?php $info['ID']?>">
  <div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="but" title=""><?php echo     $info['user_name']?></a></div>
  <div class="imagedisplay"><img src="<?php echo     "uploads/".$info['image']?>"style="width:230px; height:auto; border:1px solid #000; border-    radius:20px;"></div>
  <div class="desc"><?php echo $info['description']?></div>
  <button type="button" id="<?php echo $info['ID']?>">Like</button>


 </div>

<?php
   }
 ?>
```

Can any one help me please.

Comment: at your first div you missed a space between <?php and $info.

Comment: Quick tip: mysql_* is depricated. Use PDO instead ;)

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: hmm, it seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Add Anchor tag to Image for enable click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id  WHERE flag=1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC; ")     or die(mysql_error());


//Puts it into an array

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
//Outputs the image and other data 
?>

  <div class="test" id="<?php echo $info['ID']?>">
  <div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="but" title=""><?php echo $info['user_name']?></a></div>
  <div class="imagedisplay"><img src="<?php "uploads/".$info['image']?>"style="width:230px; height:auto; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:20px;"></div>
  <div class="desc"><?php echo $info['description']?></div>
  <button onclick="location.href='profile.php'" type="button" id="<?php echo $info['ID']?>">Like</button>
 </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

**MySQLi Solution**

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'test') or die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 


 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id  WHERE flag=1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC; ") or die(mysqli_error($con));


//Puts it into an array

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data1)){
//Outputs the image and other data 
?>

  <div class="test" id="<?php echo $info['ID']?>">
  <div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="but" title=""><?php echo $info['user_name']?></a></div>
  <div class="imagedisplay"><img src="<?php "uploads/".$info['image']?>"style="width:230px; height:auto; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:20px;"></div>
  <div class="desc"><?php echo $info['description']?></div>
  <button onclick="location.href='profile.php'" type="button" id="<?php echo $info['ID']?>">Like</button>
 </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @Déjàvu Mostly it is on by default :)

Comment: @Lanka I have updated my answer with MySQLi solution.

Comment: I don't think "mostly" is good enough. I prefer to use `<?php echo` over `<?=` even if it's shorter. I will know it always works.

Comment: @Déjàvu I have remove short tags and updated my answer.

Comment: :) you didn't have to. But it's alright i guess. (you missed a space in both solution in the first and second <div> between `echo` and `$info`)

Comment: @Lanka Please send me you file on facebook. Now I have to fix your issue.

Comment: I tried sql and sqli both. But still my problem are same. I can't click on both Link and button.

Comment: @Lanka could you provide me files?

Comment: @Lanka I'm glad to know :)